# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I was asked to prove that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$. We must show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y\in[1,\infty)$, $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}| < \epsilon$.

We first notice that $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}||\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}|$. Since $x,y\in[1,\infty)$, it follows that $x\geq1$ and $y\geq1$. Hence, $\frac1x\leq1$ and $\frac1y\leq1$. It follows that $|\frac1x+\frac1y|\leq2$.

We next notice that $|\frac1x-\frac1y|=|\frac{y-x}{xy}|=\frac{|x-y|}{|x||y|}$.We want to find a bound on the term $\frac{1}{|x||y|}$, but I am not sure how to find such a bound. We continue the proof under the assumption we found an $M>0$ such that $\frac{1}{|x||y|}<M$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Set $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$. Then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|\frac1x-\frac1y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|<\epsilon$. $\square$

My question is how to find the bound $M$. Since $x\geq1$ and $y\geq1$, it follows that $|x||y|\geq1$. Hence, $\frac{1}{|x||y|}\leq1$. It appears that $M=1$ is the appropriate bound and I have answered my own question.

Comment: $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ work. Note that $\left| \frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\right|=\frac{x+y}{x^{2}y^{2}}|x-y|$. If $x,y\in [1;+\infty[$ so $\frac{x+y}{x^{2}y^{2}}\leqslant 2$ and then $\left| \frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\right|\leqslant 2|x-y|$. Then $M=1$ as you said.

Comment: If you are particularly fond of inequalities, this method is great.  Many of us prefer the lazy way.  Here is the argument: (i)  Every Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous [obvious from definitions] (ii)  If a function has a bounded derivative then it is Lipschitz [use mean value theorem]  (iii) Is it worth my effort to compute that derivative and check it is bounded?  [In this case, yes!]

Comment: "We want to find a bound on the term $\frac {1}{|x|\cdot |y|}$..." If $x\ge 1$ and $y\ge 1$ then $|x|\cdot |y|=xy\ge 1$ so $0<\frac {1}{|x|\cdot |y|}\le 1.$ I think you will see this is obvious. It is easy to miss such obvious things.

Comment: We can also say that if $1\le x\le y$ then $|1/x^2-1/y^2|=\frac {y+x}{x^2y^2}|x-y|\le $ $\frac {2y}{x^2y^2}|x-y|=$ $=\frac {2}{x^2y}|x-y|\le \frac {2}{1^2\cdot 1}|x-y|.$

Comment: You can use the theorem that any differentiable function with a bounded derivative on it's domain is uniformly continuous. That is if you have seen this result, otherwise you should do it via methods by other commenters.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $S= \{\frac{1}{m^2}| m= \max{x,y}, \text{ where} x,y \in [1,\infty)\}.$

It is clear that $1$ is the upper bound for the set $S$. Moreover, for every $x, y \in [1,\infty)$ and there is $b \in [1,\infty)$ such that $1 < b \leq \min{x,y}$ then $M=b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{y^2}\right|=\left|\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}\right||x-y|=\left|\left(\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y\right)\frac1x\frac1y\right||x-y|\le2|x-y|.$$